# Regex to check if textfield value starts with "["

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text field that needs to be validated.The validation check needs to see if the first character in the value is a

```
"["   such as in var startValue = [start.here];
```

if the first character in `startValue` equals `"["`, then  `valid` equals `true`.

What is a regex to check to see if the first character is `"["`

I have tried

```
if ((startValue.match(/^[\[]+$/) !== null)
    validCell = true;
else 
    validCell = false;
```

thinking that this would designate the opening `\[` as a literal to be checked, but it did not work.

**NEW REQUIREMENT** Now it has to check the First AND Last character to make sure that the only thing allowed besides the regular validation rules is a function contained in "[]" anything else will fail, so I guess it is back to regex??

Comment: If you only need to test the first character, why not just compare that character to `"["`?

Comment: the regexp would be `/^\[/`

Comment: "If you only need to test the first character, why not just compare that character to "["?"
because I am absolutely super noob at regex cookie monster and I had no idea how to do that

thank you @phylax if I end up using regex and it works right, I will let you know so I can have you reply and can upvote  your answer since you actually provided the needed regex for the solution.

Comment: If you ever need to test for a sequence of characters at the beginning, and if the string may be long, then this can be beneficial: `value.lastIndexOf("foo", 0) === 0`. This ensures that the only sequence checked is that which starts at index `0`.

Comment: Who researched this snippet first: `if(somebool)somevar=true;else somevar=false;`? Why not `somevar = somebool;` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A regex seems like overkill. How about

```
validCell = startValue[0] === '[';
```

EDIT: With your new requirement, you can do this:

```
validCell = startValue[0] === '[' && startValue[startValue.length - 1] === ']';
```

Comment: You also don't need to check length first - just `startValue[0] == "["` is sufficient.

Comment: Testing now, I just immediately went to regex because of days worth of field level validation that has required. Will mark accepted if this works, will provide extra info if not.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - yeah, I was thinking Java :P

Comment: @JonSmith - Note the updated syntax. I was answering for the wrong language.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Hilarious...for a matter of fact, so hilarious I got in trouble for disturbing my coworkers when I began to laugh hilariously at work....thanks :)

Comment: I marked this as correct because until the requirements changed, it was the correct answer. With the requirements change, I ended up figuring out the regex on my own as I have posted next.

Comment: @JonSmith - I edited my answer to address the new requirement. Still no need to use regex.

Answer (score 0):

After a requirements change made me check the **FIRST AND LAST** to ensure only values inside a set of brackets **[like this]** did not get validated I thought I figured out the regex to handle the validation.

```
if(rangeFrom.match(/^\[|\[$/)){
        isValid = true;
        funcFromCheck = true;
    }  
else
    funcFromCheck = false;
```

But this appears to be wrong as it is not changing the funcFromCheck to false on this value:

[failme

and since this doesn't end with ], then it should fail, right?